# How to handle ajax response behind changing state of an element?

Tags: python, asp.net, ajax, scrapy

I'm crawling an asp.net page with one form on it, which contains multiple select tags with different options. Each select tag has a JavaScript function attached which is triggered every time a different value is selected. That JS function performs an AJAX call which returns a text response similar to JSON, but it's text.

Here it is

> 51.772425|0.00|21.33|0.00|5000|51.772425|0

I want to intercept it with Scrapy, but instead of getting just this little piece of string I got the whole page.

'NJGroup123390' It's the ID of select tag

Here's my code:

```
        def after_login(self, response):
            return Request(url='https://****.com/NexJobPage.asp?Id=445',
                                            callback=self.parse_form)

    def parse_form(self, response):
            return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formdata={'NJGroup123390':'5000'},
                                    dont_click=True,
                                    callback=self.parse_form2)]

    # here I should have the response returned by AJAX: 51.772425|0.00|21.33|0.00|5000|51.772425|0
    def parse_form2(self, response):
            f = open('logo2', 'wb')
            f.write(response.body)
            f.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have missing an additional argument or header added through javascript. Inspect the request sent in your browser, check for missing parameters, headers or cookies and add them to your request object.

You can use the shell to see what is the data filled by `FormRequest`:

```
$ scrapy shell https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup
2014-02-12 19:38:12-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
...

In [1]: from scrapy.http import FormRequest

In [2]: req = FormRequest.from_response(response, formnumber=1)

In [3]: import urlparse

In [4]: urlparse.parse_qs(req.body, True)
Out[4]: 
{'display-name': [''],
 'email': [''],
 'fkey': ['324799e03d5f73e1af72134e6d943f58'],
 'password': [''],
 'password2': [''],
 'submit-button': ['Sign Up']}
```